# redirects for removed/deleted woocommerce products

Tags: redirect, woocommerce-offtopic, seo, automation, customization

I need to remove some discontinued products from a woocommerce site. I'm just wondering how to go about automating this. I haven't figured out whether to throw a 301, 404 or 410 error, but either way, is there an easy way to automate this for future removed products?

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Found [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/auto-redirect-404/), but it's not updated. But if you can manage manual process, I found [Redirection plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) a good one for redirection. I tried something like [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/210529/22728), but you can see, it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually use PHP to make redirects, rather than just .htaccess, which has the benefit of allowing you to use variables.

I don't really know woocommerce too well but you could create a redirect similar to this.

Note this is pseudo code. These function calls are fictional but the logic
will still apply

```
function redirect_product() {

    $product_status = get_product(); 

    $product_url = get_product_url();  

    if ($product_status === NULL) {

       $URL = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
       if ( $URL == $product_url) {
         header( 'HTTP/1.0 301 Moved Permanently' );
         header( 'Location: /' ); //redirect to url of your choosing
         exit();
       } else {
         return;
       }
    }
}
```