# Set Attachment Image File URL as GUID

Tags: attachments, wp-update-post, guids

I have a form that uploads images and i want to update the GUID to be the attachment file url after WP generates the metadata.

I tried to use `wp_update_post`, but seems that is not updating the `guid`.

```
$attachments = get_posts($post_data);

if ($attachments) {
    // attach images to gallery
    foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {

        wp_update_post(array(
                'ID' => $attachment->ID,
                'post_status' => 'inherit',
                'post_parent' => $gallery_post_id,
                'guid' = wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID);
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: I'm not an SQL wiz, but it would probably involve `UPDATE wp_posts SET  guid = REPLACE (guid, 'http://www.oldsiteurl.com', 'http://yourcdn.newsiteurl.com') WHERE post_type = 'attachment';`

Comment: Don't mess with the `GUID`: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/90209/21376

Comment: Why do you want to update the GUID? They aren't URLs, they're unique identifiers.

Comment: The thing is that theme's gallery wants image src and its takes the guid. So i looked into the database and when i changed manually the guid to file url, gallery worked. Bad code from theme devs.... Thank you all

Comment: A GUID Gallery? Worst Gallery Ever!

Comment: Your theme code is horrific. The GUID ***is not an URL*** and should not be used as one (Follow the link in my previous comment)

Comment: Maybe you should rephrase that question and ask how to get rid of that awful piece of gallery code.

Comment: I found the code that overides the GUID with the attachment file url and i modified it. Thank you guys